# sort from information from a text file Python 3

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to open text file with a 100 random numbers. Then reading them and sorting this numbers from lowest to highest.

I've created the file and written the 100 random numbers through this function.

```
def hundred_values():
    import random
    numbers_list = []
    for _ in range(100):
        numbers_list.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(numbers_list))
```

after this I'm trying to get Python to read the file, changing the string into int to then sorting them from lowest to highest. But I can't get it to work. Any input would be greatly appreciated

```
def find_smallest_number():
    lines = []
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file:
        line = file.read().splitlines() # for processing
        lines.append(line) # storing everything in memory
        lines.sort(lines)
        print(lines)
```

Comment: You're probably reading in strings and then getting lexicographical ordering rather than numerical ordering.

Comment: That could probably be it. Any input of how I could convert it?

Comment: `find_smallest_number` is a misleading name. `read_sort_print` might be better, but it's pretty vague

Comment: wjandrea - I know, it's in the process of being changed. I tried to make it do both reading, listing and then writing in a single function which I later changed my mind about. Just haven't changed the name. Thanks for pointing it out do. Will get on it straight away.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing the entire list in a single line, what you will see in the file is this: `[8, 2, 4, ...]`, that's why you can't sort it. It's better to store each value in a single line if you don't want to use `csv` or `json` format. For example:

```py
import random


def hundred_values():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
        for _ in range(100):
            print(random.randint(1, 100), file=file)


def find_smallest_number():
    with open('numbers.txt') as file:
        values = sorted([int(i) for i in file.readlines()])
        print(values)


hundred_values()
find_smallest_number()

>>> [1, 5, 5, 6, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 13, ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here. The first, and most important, is that you're writing the string representation of a list to the file. This is going to cause you pain right from the start. Second, you'll want to read in integers and not strings so that your ordering is correct (if they are strings, you'll get lexicographical ordering). So, it needs to be corrected at the source.

This is how to generate the file:

```
import random # get the import out of the function and in the global scope

def hundred_values():

    numbers_list = []

    for _ in range(100):
        numbers_list.append(random.randint(1, 100))
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join([str(item) for item in numbers_list])) # use join with a newline character to get an actual list

hundred_values()
```

Then you can read and sort it like so:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()

data = [int(item) for item in data] # make sure that we have ints so we can have numerical ordering
data.sort() # Sort the list in-place
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! This really did do the trick. Only issue I'm running into now is that I get an output which is just a list sorted from 1 - 100 in the terminal when I run print(data) and now the random ints from numbers.txt

Comment: @LukeRhinehart_ sorry, I'm not sure I understand the issue. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. English is my second language so sometimes I still struggle to put my thoughts forward. When I ran print(data) from the second function it gave me a list in the terminal of 1-99 listed in order from lowest to highest number. What I'm asking is why it doesn't give me the numbers read from numbers.txt sorted from lowest to highest.

Comment: That's fine. I just don't quite understand the issue you're describing. Take your time. I will adapt my answer if I can

Comment: I'm just posting this again in case you didn't see my edited comment

 When I ran print(data) from the second function it gave me a list in the terminal of 1-99 listed in order from lowest to highest number. What I'm asking is why it doesn't give me the numbers read from numbers.txt sorted from lowest to highest